# Dropdown menu in navbar not staying open when hovering over it

Tags: html, css

i have a question for you guys , i have made a navbar for my website , but i can't cope with the dropdown menu . The problem is that when I want all the links to be in the middle of the navbar , but when i hover over the navigation dropdonw menu , it won't stay open on hover. I know i can fix this by adding li float:left instead of li display:inline, but then all the links go to the left , so my question is: is there a way in which all my links could be centered in the middle of my navbar and my navigation dropdonw menu could stay open on hover ? This is my code:

```css
nav  {
    
    font-size:75%;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     color:darkgrey;     
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    
}



.dropdown-content {
    
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 134px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>

<body>  
<nav>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="mainpage.html">Начало</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" >
                <a href="zafirmata.html" class="dropbtn">За фирмата</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a  href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a  href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a  href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="zasobstvenika1CV.html">За собствениците</a></li>
            <li><a href="produkti.html">Продукти</a></li>
            <li><a href="porachki.html">Поръчки</a></li>
            <li><a href="mneniq.html">Мнения</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I actually have no idea how does it work in this online editor , but it does not work for me when i do it ! Please halppp !

Comment: since it works fine here....Is this all your codes?...what browser and browser version  are you using so that the expected result is not working?

Comment: Well im using chrome and i think its the latest version . Actually just now i found out that the video that i put right below the dropdown is causing the problems , so when i moved it the dropdown works fine ! I still , however, have no clue why it was bugged when the video was below it !

Comment: hmmm......probably look into the css rules for the video container or its parent container...Put that video html codes (if it is not lengthy) in your question, it is better to understand what the issue is from someone who does....